# Pivot tables to sumifs

Tags: excel

I'm trying to convert pivot table to sumifs.I have applied 3 filters to it. The formula is working fine except for "**All**".I believe there is some changes in the setting I should make.

The formula I'm implementing is:

```
=SUMIFS(SalesTable[Revenue],SalesTable[Product Category],$K7,SalesTable[Year],Q$6,SalesTable[Country],IF($C$1="(All)","*",$C$1),SalesTable[Customer Gender],IF($C$2="(All)","*",$C$2),SalesTable[Age Group],IF($C$3="(All)","*",$C$3))
```

Image on the left is the one on which I am facing problem.
Image on the right is the desired output.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the spreadsheet on the left, the filter cells don't show "(All)" but "All" without brackets. Adjust your formula to search for the text "all", so the result will be positive with or without brackets. You can use the Search() function for that. Search() is not case sensitive. If the search text is found in a cell, Search() will return the number of the start position of that text in the cell. If the text is not found, Search() returns an error.

Hence you can check if Search() returns a number and then go for the "*" wildcard.

```
=SUMIFS(SalesTable[revenue],
SalesTable[product category],$K7,
SalesTable[year],Q$6,
SalesTable[Country],IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($C$1,"all")),"*",$C$1),
SalesTable[Customer Gender],IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($C$2,"All")),"*",$C$2),
SalesTable[Age group],IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($C$3,"All")),"*",$C$3))
```